# Function equal to Ctrl+Shift+I

Tags: front-end, legending, keyboard, input-forms

No, it's not `InputForm`. Consider this example:

```
p = Show[ListPlot[{1}, PlotLegends -> "1"], ListPlot[{2}, PlotLegends -> "2"]];
```

This is the output of `p // InputForm`:

[image]

while this is what you'll see if you execute `p` and select the output and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>:

[image]

Can I get the 
output of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> with a function rather than keyboard shortcut?

What? Why I'm interested in such a boring question? Well, I encountered this when trying to do some direct modification on the legends. Try the following example:

```
data1 = Sin@Range[1, 10, 0.1];
data2 = Cos@Range[1, 10, 0.1];

pline = ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}, PlotLegends -> {"line1", "line2"}];

ppoint = ListPlot[{data1, data2}, PlotMarkers -> "0", PlotLegends -> {"point", "point2"}];

pjoin = Show[pline, ppoint];
pjoin /. Legended[Legended[a_, {Placed[b_, c__]}], {Placed[d_, e__]}] :> 
  Legended[a, Placed[Grid[{{b}, {d}}, Frame -> True], c]]
```

[image]

The last line added one frame for the different sorts of legends. Dirty, right? And it'll be dirtier if we have more sorts of legends. However, if the output of `p` is baptized by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (actually you just need to copy and paste it) then a much simpler pattern can be used!:

```
(* copy and paste the graphics here *) /. Grid[a__] :> Grid[a, Frame -> True]
```

The resulted graphics is the same so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: xzczd, I have marked this question as a duplicate because I believe it is one.  Please review it and let me know if it is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This points out that `Legended` is typeset instead of being evaluated in the kernel evaluation time. The evidence is in that `InputForm[p]` still contains two `Legended`s and the graphics only one.

This is what you need:

```
Show[ListPlot[Range[10], PlotLegends -> {"a"}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListPlot[Range[10] + 2, PlotLegends -> {"b"}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]] // ToBoxes // MakeExpression // InputForm // ReleaseHold
```

`ToBoxes` forces `Legended` to do its business to resolve multiple `Legended`s during the evaluation time and `MakeExpression` reconstructs expressions from boxes so you can further parse.