# How to combine several legends in one frame?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, frame

I'm using `Show` to combine three plots. The code I write is as follows:

```
g1 = Plot[x^2 + 3, {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{TraditionalForm[k == 1]}, 
      LegendLayout -> "Row", 
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0] & )], Below], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red];
g2 = Plot[x^3 + x, {x, 1, 4}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{TraditionalForm[k == 2]}, 
      LegendLayout -> "Row", 
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0] & )], Below], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
g3 = Plot[20/x, {x, 1/2, 4}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{TraditionalForm[k == 3]}, 
      LegendLayout -> "Row", 
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0] & )], Below], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Black];
Show[{g1, g2, g3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, All}}]
```

The output is the following:
[image]

As we can see in the output, the three legends are seperate in three frames. How can I place the three legends in a row in one frame?

Comment: This answer might be useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127213/8822

Comment: Thanks for your info!

Answer (score 6):

```
show = Show[{g1, g2, g3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, All}}];
```

Extract the main plot and legends from `show` and reorganize them in desired form:

```
plot = Cases[show, _Graphics, All][[1]];

legendargs = Transpose @
   Cases[show, LineLegend[arg1_, arg2_, opts___] :> {arg1, arg2, opts}, All];

newlegend = Placed[LineLegend @@ legendargs, 
    ## & @@ First @ Cases[show, Placed[_, a___] :> {a}, All]];


Legended[plot, newlegend]
```

[image]

Comment: It indicates an error when I run the code `newlegend = Placed[LineLegend @@ legendargs, 
    ## & @@ First @ Cases[show, Placed[_, a___] :> {a}, All]]`. Did you miss something in this code?

Comment: @YaHe, what is the error message?

Comment: It indicates that "First::nofirst, the length of {} is zero, there is no first element"

Comment: how about `Cases[show, _Graphics, All][[1]]`? what does it give?

Comment: It is normal. The only abnormal one is `newlegend = Placed[LineLegend @@ legendargs, 
    ## & @@ First @ Cases[show, Placed[_, a___] :> {a}, All]];`

Comment: It  could be version/os difference (I am using V13.1.0 on Linux). Try `newlegend=Placed[LineLegend @@ legendargs, Below]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145693/discussion-between-ya-he-and-kglr).

Comment: Many thanks. It works now (I'm also using V13.1). Besides, by reducing the `FrameMargins` in the plot g1, g2, g3, I can reduce the margin of the legends frame in the final output.

Answer (score 4):

```
With[{ll = LineLegend}, 
 ToExpression@
   ToBoxes@Show[{g1, g2, g3}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, All}}] //. {ll[{a1__}, {b1__}, c__], 
    ll[{a2_}, {b2_}, c__], rest___} :> {ll[{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, c], rest}]
```

To understand why `ToBoxes` and `ToExpression` are used, read the following:

[Graphics in Notebook Different from Graphics Expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45808/1871)

[Function equal to Ctrl+Shift+I](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76056/1871)

Comment: Thanks! Your proposal works well!

Comment: I have one question about your code. Sometimes the combined legend may be displayed in two rows (this happens when each legend is a bit long). Do you know how to make the combined legend always shown in one row?

Comment: @YaHe It's answered in this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26231/1871

Comment: Thanks! I have solved the problem.

Comment: @YaHe Then you should tell kglr you've solved this.

Comment: Ok, I will tell him